# How to scroll to last element of li in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my code. I need help to scroll to the last element of the list in JavaScript.

```
<ul class="messages" id="chatBox">
  <!-- ngRepeat: message in message -->
  <li ng-repeat="message in message" class="server">
    <div>
      <p class="usrname ng-binding"></p>
      <p class="dataMessage ng-binding">you have connected to angularjs</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: message in message -->
  <li ng-repeat="message in message" class="mymsg">
    <div>
      <p class="usrname ng-binding">ketan</p>
      <p class="dataMessage ng-binding">xcxz</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: message in message -->
  <li ng-repeat="message in message" class="mymsg">
    <div>
      <p class="usrname ng-binding">ketan</p>
      <p class="dataMessage ng-binding">czxc</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: message in message -->
  <li ng-repeat="message in message" class="mymsg">
    <div>
      <p class="usrname ng-binding">ketan</p>
      <p class="dataMessage ng-binding">czxc</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: message in message -->
  <li ng-repeat="message in message" class="mymsg">
    <div>
      <p class="usrname ng-binding">ketan</p>
      <p class="dataMessage ng-binding">cxz</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: message in message -->
  <li ng-repeat="message in message" class="mymsg">
    <div>
      <p class="usrname ng-binding">ketan</p>
      <p class="dataMessage ng-binding">cxzczx</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: message in message -->
</ul>
```

Comment: here my ul height is 200px so some of the contents goes up

Comment: Share your code. What you did till now?

Comment: your question is very unclear. Please post some html and js code and explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: `document.querySelector("#chatBox li.mymsg:last-child").scrollIntoView()`

Answer (score 0):

Try using scrollIntoView() method to scroll to last element or any element you want.

$(selector).scrollIntoView();